# Extension UIScrollView in one target. Use extended methods in UITableView instance will crash in another target

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

In Cocoa Touch Framework Target. I add following methods to UIScrollView.

```
public extension UIScrollView {

  public func beginRefresh() {
    print("beginRefresh")
  }

  public func endRefresh() {
    print("endRefresh")
  }

}
```

In iOS App Target as Demo App. I invoke those methods on UITableView instance. It crash.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.beginRefresh()
}
```

Crash Log:

> 2016-08-10 16:22:29.736 DTRefresh iOS Example[7373:210619]
>   -[UITableView beginRefresh]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc91b019e00 2016-08-10 16:22:29.751 DTRefresh iOS
>   Example[7373:210619] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView beginRefresh]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc91b019e00'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c39d85 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010b9dddeb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000109c42d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b88cfa
>   ___forwarding_** + 970    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b888a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   DTRefresh iOS
>   Example               0x0000000109a54a81
>   _TFC21DTRefresh_iOS_Example18ListViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 561   6   DTRefresh iOS Example               0x0000000109a54b22
>   _TToFC21DTRefresh_iOS_Example18ListViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34  7   UIKit                               0x000000010a5fc984
>   -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198     8   UIKit                               0x000000010a5fccd3 -[UIViewController view] + 27    9   UIKit
>   0x000000010a4d2fb4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] +
>   61    10  UIKit                               0x000000010a4d369d
>   -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282  11  UIKit                               0x00000001193a5d16 -[UIWindowAccessibility
>   _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 68     12  UIKit                               0x000000010a4e5180 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42   13  UIKit
>   0x000000010a459ed9 -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131   14  UIKit                               0x000000010a460568
>   -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1769   15  UIKit                               0x000000010a45d714
>   -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d86e8c8
>   **FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24     17  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d86e741
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 178  18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d86eaca -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] +
>   45    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b5f301
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b5522c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556   21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b546e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867     22  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000109b540f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488     23  UIKit
>   0x000000010a45cf21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402    24  UIKit
>   0x000000010a461f09 UIApplicationMain + 171    25  DTRefresh iOS Example 
>   0x0000000109a54662 main + 114     26  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010c4a192d start + 1  27  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: By the way. In iOS App Target. I invoke those methods on UIScrollView instance. Everything is fine.

Comment: Everything is ok with code you posted. Issue somewhere else.